# Use openrailwaymap offline

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, mapping

I have a one question: it's possibile to create an offline map of openrailwaymap?

I would create an offline map using openstreetmap and after add the openrailwaymap layer...

Comment: OpenRailwayMap uses OpenStreetMap data only. There is no additional "layer" as far as I know.

Comment: Download the OSM data and and extract the the railway tag. > https://download.geofabrik.de/ (you can use QGIS offline with the shapefiles)